# Add/change timezone on Ubuntu Minimal 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-minimal, timezone

I have an instance running Ubuntu Minimal 18.04 LTS on Google Cloud.

I want to change the system timezone, but `timedatectl list-timezones` shows only UTC, so `timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>` fails because any `<timezone>` other than UTC is invalid.

How do I add a timezone so that I can then set the system to it?

Thanks!

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: @Nmath It gave me a rather long error, basically saying that tzdata wasn't installed. I did `sudo apt install tzdata` and it installed lots of timezones, so now I can change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by installing the package `tzdata`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tzdata
```

...which installs the timezone database and also asks for the preferred timezone during installation.